# VBA - Loop Through Worksheets to Add Months of Year to Combo Boxes

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have Private Sub combo boxes on 20 worksheets. I am trying to preload the months of the year in the combo boxes but I cant seem to make it work. What's wrong with my present code? It only adds the 12 months like, 120 times into the first combo box:

```
Sub WorkBook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "January"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "February"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "March"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "April"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "May"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "June"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "July"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "August"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "September"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "October"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "November"
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "December"
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `ws.ComboBox1.AddItem "January"` etc.

Comment: gives me "method or data member not found" error

Comment: You don't have a ComboBox1 on each worksheet, at least not under that name.

Comment: They are all ComboBox1 I am copy/pasting the name ComboBox1 right from the properties dialogue

Comment: you can also do something like this `for i=1 to 12:ws.combobox1.additem format(dateserial(2017,i,1),"mmmm"): next i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're looping through your sheets using the `ws` variable, but for each worksheet you're adding the months to your currently `ActiveSheet`. You could do a `ws.Activate` before the first `ActiveSheet.Combobox...` line, however - that's just plain bad practice (see [how to avoid Select / Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

**Bad example:**

```
Sub WorkBook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Activate
   ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "January"
   ActiveSheet.ComboBox1.AddItem "February"
   '....
Next ws
End Sub
```

It's better to use the `ws` variable and then access the controls through the `OLEObjects` collection.

**Good example:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws.OLEObjects("Combobox1").Object
        For i = 1 To 12
            .AddItem Format(DateSerial(2017, i, 1), "mmmm") 'as per comment!
        Next i
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This is it. Amazing!

Comment: You're welcome. B.t.w. keep in mind that this will error for Worksheets that do not have the "ComboBox1" object, so you might want to add some checks and/or error handling.